# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC When trying to communicate through ObjectOuputStream

Tags: java, javafx, objectoutputstream

I am using a ClientHandler in the Server side to handle Communication and a ServerConnection on the client side to Handle the communication there.

Here is the ClientHandler (Server- Side)

```
public void run() {

    System.out.println("Running");
    try {
        input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (isListening) {

        try {



            String packetMessageJson = (String) input.readObject();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            PacketMessage packetMessage = gson.fromJson(packetMessageJson, PacketMessage.class);

            Double auctionID = null;


            switch (packetMessage.getType()) {
```

This uses works fine until I do this twice. From the client side

ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
objectOutputStream.writeObject(sampleObject)

What precautions should there be?

The error AC When trying to communicate pops up. I know that this  means I am initializing the ObjectOutputStream twice but is there a way around this so I can use the JavaFx controllers to switch between views without initializng twice

Comment: *"This uses works fine until I do this twice."* - Yup. See the first duplink for why. *"Is there a way around this?"* There is a hacky way (see 2nd duplink) but it has subtle problems.  You are better off using JSON end-to-end in this case (IMO).

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @StephenC I am using end to end Gson conversion communication since this is TCP and I need to cast packets.

Comment: Umm ... you misunderstand what I am saying.  Your code show that you are using `ObjectStream` to pass a string that contains a JSON encoding over a socket stream.  THEN you use GSON to parse the JSON and create a `PacketMessage` from it. Why don't you just pass the `String` as text over the stream?  That way you can pass as many of them as you want.   If you look at `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` and the `readUTF`/`writeUTF` methods, you will see a way to transfer strings as units.